# db2 stored procedure - trouble batching DELETE statements

Tags: sql, loops, cursor, db2, commit

I've only been writing DB2 procedures for a few days, but trying to do a "batch delete" on a given table. My expected logic is:

- to open a cursor
- walk through it until EOF
- issue a DELETE on each iteration

For sake of simplifying this question, assume I only want to issue a single COMMIT (of all DELETEs), after the WHILE loop is completed (ie. once cursor reaches EOF). So given the  code sample below:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (colA INTEGER, ...)


CREATE PROCEDURE "SCHEMA"."PURGE_PROC"
(IN batchSize INTEGER)
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC SQL140207163731500
BEGIN

   DECLARE tempID             INTEGER;
   DECLARE eof_bool           INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE sqlString          VARCHAR(1000);
   DECLARE sqlStmt            STATEMENT;
   DECLARE myCurs             CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR sqlStmt;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET eof_bool = 1;

   SET sqlString = 'select colA from TableA';
   PREPARE sqlStmt FROM sqlString;

   OPEN myCurs;
   FETCH myCurs INTO tempID;
   WHILE (eof_bool = 0) DO
        DELETE FROM TableA where colA = tempID;
        FETCH myCurs INTO tempID;
   END WHILE;

   COMMIT;
   CLOSE myCurs;

END
```

Note: In my real scenario:

- I am not deleting all records from the table, just certain ones based on some additional criteria; and
- I plan to perform a COMMIT every N# iterations of the WHILE loop (say 500 or 1000), not the entire mess like above; and
- I plan to DELETE against multiple tables, not just this one;

But again, to simplify, I tested the above code, and what I'm seeing is that the DELETEs seem to be getting committed 1-by-1. I base this on the following test:

- I pre-load the table with (say 50k) records;
- then run the purge storedProc which takes ~60 secs to run;
- during this time, from another sql client, I continuously "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA" and see count reducing incrementally.

If all DELETEs were committed at once, I would expect to see the record count(*) only drop from  to 0 at the end of the ~60 seconds. That is what I see with comparable SPs written for Oracle or SQLServer.

This is DB2 v9.5 on Win2003.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Your code makes a commit all at once, not 1 by 1. How can you know the  code is committing one by one? a select WITH UR will tell you the modified rows, but not commited.

Comment: I think you have to be more punctual with your question, because it seems it is a opinion question, and this is not the place to put questions like that. You have to tell your problem, show what you have done, and explain clearly what you want to get.

Comment: As I told Mustaccio below, I guess you guys are right that it is doing a single commit.  Some background...I have this same db structure in Oracle, SQLServer, and DB2. I have a jdbc-based purge application that I can run against all 3.  I am now writing a storedProcedure alternative for each of the 3 dbs. The Oracle and SQLServer SPs show 10x improvement over the JDBC. The DB2 SP only shows 2x improvement. This surprising slowness, plus seeing (what I now realize were uncommitted read) record counts reduce 1-by-1 made me think additional commits were occurring.

Comment: Hmm... if possible, I'd still recommend deleting in a set-based way (ie, not in a cursor), as that should help speed things up further.  Obviously you still have to issue multiple `DELETE`s, but there are ways to deal with that - like inserting ids into a temp table, or similar.  60s for only 50k records is pretty slow - you're doing a straight read through a table (or possibly an index) so most of your time is taken by the looping logic and row-by-agonizing-row delete.

Comment: I'd agree with @Clockwork-Muse, a set base solution would be preferred on any RDBMS.  50K shouldn't be a problem for a single commit.  100K even.  1M might be a problem.

Comment: @Charles - While a single transaction may certainly be able to handle that volume of records, doing so may have knock-on effects in a concurrent system.  Depending on the number of sessions/other stuff, you _want_ smaller transactions... especially as optimizers reserve the right to lock the **entire** table if you're holding on to too many records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the difference in concurrency control implementation between the different database engines. In an Oracle database another session would see data that have been committed prior to the beginning of its transaction, that is, it would not see any deletes until the first session commits.

In DB2, depending on the server configuration parameters (e.g. `DB2_SKIPDELETED`) and/or the second session isolation level (e.g. uncommitted read) it can in fact see (or not see) data affected by in-flight transactions.

If your business logic requires different transaction isolation, speak with your DBA.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess I was seeing uncommitted row counts with my 2nd session...guess it was in fact doing a single commit. I'm struggling with the management tools (as compared to other RDBMSs), I think I need to look at something on the server side to monitor COMMITs. I'll work with a DBA.

Comment: I think you were **not** seeing the deleted row though they were still not committed. At least that's what follows from your description.

Comment: No, here is what I would see...Again, I load up the table with 50k records, run the purge rec which takes about 60 secs to complete:

Comment: (disregard previous comment..edit timed out on me) No, here is what I would see...Again, I load up the table with 50k records, run the purge rec which takes about 60 secs to complete, and here is what the 2nd SQL client/session would show with a simple "select count(*) from tableA":                           
Time 0s  = 50,000 recs
Time 20s = 34,517 recs
Time 40s = 17,102 recs
Time 60s = 0 recs

This would imply I **was** seeing deleted rows, even though they were not yet committed.

Comment: 34517 records is less than 50000 records, so you are **not** seeing 16483 records that have been deleted, though not committed. Right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Semantics confusion on my part I guess. I "don't see recs that have been deleted yet not committed" == I "do see the rec count reflecting rows deleted yet not committed".

Answer (score 0):

It should be pointed out that you're deleting "outside of the cursor"

The right way to delete using the cursor would be using a "positioned delete"

```
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE CURRENT OF myCurs;
```

The above deletes the row just fetched.

Comment: Thanks, if I understand correctly, your suggestion will speed up the Deletes on this single table. But if this colA is a key across multiple other tables which also need deleting in the loop (which is my utlimate scenario), I'd need to use the temp variable approach. Correct?